# How to set up a test in jest to check for existence of elements with specific data attributes in dom

Tags: javascript, testing, dom, jestjs

Im testing my javascript class with jest, here's the relevant part of the class :

```
class ContentEditable {
  constructor(editableKind){
    this.editables =  document.querySelectorAll(`[data-editablekind='${editableKind}']`);
    this.editionStrategy = this.getStrategy(editableKind)
  }
}
```

In the test Id like to check that this.editables is returning the right stuff (a Nodelist of the right size). So the idea behind the test is to create a div with the right attribute then instanciate the class and check for the length of `editables`

```
test('editables of kind text', () => {
  let element = document.createElement("div");
  element.dataset.editablekind = 'text'
  console.log(element.dataset.editablekind)
  const contentEditable = new ContentEditable('text')
  expect([...contentEditable.editables].length).toEqual(1);
});
```

However `contentEditable.editables` seems to stay empty whatever I do. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Well, you are not appending this "element" you've created to some other document element

Comment: why would I append it ? Im just trying to check if ```document.querySelectorAll(`[data-editablekind='${editableKind}']`);``` selected it...

Comment: When you do document.createElement, you don't actually append  it to document, querySelector sees only whats appended.
You would need to append this element created to document, so you could find it in querySelector

Comment: thanks I didnt realise that you needed to append to document